# how to create a same name directory in other directory?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

For example. 
if I have /tmp directory, that contains /test1, /test2, /test3 and on..
I have to move this /test* directories to /tmp2 directory.
after that I have to create a same name directories in /tmp3 directory.

so in /tmp 
---/test1, /test2, /test3 and on and on 
use mv /test* /tmp2 
move all directories that starts with test to tmp2

but at /tmp3 I have to CREATE ALL DIRECTORIES that is in tmp2.. not the files or directories inside of it.. but just the name of the directory

at the end there should be
/tmp2 - /test1 /test2 /test3 ....
/tmp3 - /test1 /test2 /tets3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find`:

```
while read -r dir
do
  mv "/tmp/$dir" /tmp2
  mkdir "/tmp3/$dir"
done < <(find /tmp/test* -maxdepth 0 -type d -printf "%f\n")
```

Comment: Probably better to say `find /tmp2 -maxdepth 1 ...` rather than having the shell expand the list itself.

Comment: @ccarton I agree, but then you get a variable with the value `tmp2`. Do you know a way to avoid that?

Comment: let me fix my question, I want to create a directories that I just moved from tmp to tmp2.. not what was already in tmp2

Comment: it looks like it is not working.. I think it is because you FIND command is checking after the file is moved.. i tried moving that find command around.. but getting few different errors.

Comment: I solve the problem.. i think your answer should be find /tmp2/test* instead of /tmp/test* ... Thank you so much for your help

Comment: You say you want to find everything in `/tmp/test*` first, so the answer should be correct. Please [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it helpful.